# I am installing pysentiment in conda but i got this error

Tags: python, anaconda, setup.py

I input `pip install pysentiment` in anaconda prompt but i got this error

> ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\LHICEL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b4p7exje\pysentiment\

How can i solve this? I tried updating set up tools by `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools` in conda prompt but it did not solve the problem

Thank you

Comment: This looks very much like you have a 32-bit system and you are running a DOS command interpreter (`command.com`) instead of a Windows console (`cmd.exe`). No other way to reasonably explain the 8.3 folder name in the prompt.

Comment: what do you suggest i do?

Comment: To get a Windows console, run `cmd.exe` not `command.com`.

Comment: I am running the pip install in a anaconda prompt